# react redux toolkit how to reflect changes of every single items price after change the quantity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Right now I can reflect changes of total price if quantity changes. here is an example what I am doing now:

```
price of every single item 
quantity {2} {200}
quantity {2} {100}
    
total: price = 600
```

Here is  my cart slice:

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    items: [],
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addItem(state, action) {
      const { id, title, price, size, color, image, quantity = 1 } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.quantity += quantity;
      } else {
        state.items.push({ id, title, price, size, color, image, quantity });
      }
      state.total += price * quantity;
      
    },
    removeItem(state, action) {
      const { id, quantity = state.quantity } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      if (existingItem) {
        if (existingItem.quantity > quantity) {
          existingItem.quantity -= quantity;
        } else {
          state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        }
        state.total -= existingItem.price * quantity;
      }
    },
    removeSingleItem(state, action) {
      const { id, quantity = 1 } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      if (existingItem) {
        if (existingItem.quantity > quantity) {
          existingItem.quantity -= quantity;
        } else {
          state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        }
        state.total -= existingItem.price * quantity;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addItem,
  removeItem,
  addSingleItem,
  removeSingleItem
} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

My expected result will be:

```
price of every single item 
quantity {2} {400}
quantity {2} {200}
    
total: price = 600
```

Comment: Can you please provide a better description of your problem? What should be your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React state should be the minimum data it takes to represent the "state"; it's considered a bit of a React anti-pattern to store derived state in state. In this case a cart total can be computed directly from the `state.cart.items` array.

Example:

```js
const items = useSelector(state => state.cart.items);

const total = items.reduce((total, { price = 0, quantity = 0 }) => {
  return total + price * quantity;
}, 0);
```

If you want or need to you can memoize the total using the `useMemo` hook.

```js
const items = useSelector(state => state.cart.items);

const total = useMemo(() => {
  return items.reduce((total, { price = 0, quantity = 0 }) => {
    return total + price * quantity;
  }, 0);
}, [items]);
```

`redux-toolkit` also exports `reselect` functions. You could use [`createSelector`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) to create a memoized selector function. In the `cartSlice` file create an input selector to select the `state.cart.items` array and then create the memoized selector`.

```js
import { createSlice, createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  ...
});

export const cartItemsSelector = state => state.cart.items;

export const cartTotalSelector = createSelector(
  [cartItemsSelector],
  items => items.reduce((total, { price = 0, quantity = 0 }) => {
    return total + price * quantity;
  }, 0)
);
```

```js
const items = useSelector(cartItemsSelector);
const total = useSelector(cartTotalSelector);

...
```

Remove the `total` state and logic from the cart slice.

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    items: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addItem(state, action) {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);

      if (existingItem) {
        existingItem.quantity += quantity;
      } else {
        state.items.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 });
      }
    },
    removeItem(state, action) {
      const { id, quantity = 1 } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);

      if (existingItem) {
        if (existingItem.quantity > quantity) {
          existingItem.quantity -= quantity;
        } else {
          state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        }
      }
    },
    removeSingleItem(state, action) {
      const { id, quantity = 1 } = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      if (existingItem) {
        if (existingItem.quantity > quantity) {
          existingItem.quantity -= quantity;
        } else {
          state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        }
      }
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addItem,
  removeItem,
  addSingleItem,
  removeSingleItem
} = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `total` in state. You can derive that from the `items` array. Read more about defining a minimal representation of state [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state).

So you should remove any mention of `total` in your slice.

After that, once you update the `items` array with quantity and price, you can use a selector to get the total from that.

```js
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const total = useSelector((state) => state.cart.items.reduce((a, b) => a + b.quantity, 0))
```

Here we're using a selector which takes `state` as an argument, which allows us to access the `cart` slice. From the `cart` slice we access the `items` array and use the `reduce` [array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to derive the total quantity.